# Liferay Map Journal Article to FriendlyUrl

Tags: liferay

I have Liferay articles (at their latest version) and want to get their friendlyUrl. I know that the friendlyUrl is in the Layout table but I don't know how to map my article there.

The internet and Liferay's documentation don't seem to be of help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Get the articleId
2. Get the layoutIds it appears in
3. Get all Layout objects
4. For each Layout get the friendlyUrl

   ```
   List<Long> layoutIds = JournalContentSearchLocalServiceUtil.getLayoutIds(groupId, false, articleId); // all the layoutIds
   Layout layout = LayoutLocalServiceUtil.getLayout(groupId, false, layoutId.get(x)); 
   layout.getFriendlyURL();
   ```